# Firebase Simple Auth API Pricing Clarification

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

After reading all the documentation about Firebase Auth/Pricing, I do not find anything about the simple API [princing](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing) (not phone authentication).

Suppose if I have a one cloud-function, and this cloud-function call the method `admin.auth().getUser('someId')` 5 thousand times, I will be charged? how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no charge for looking up a user from the Admin SDK. You may get rate limited if your usage may affect the system, but you won't be charged for the calls.

Answer (score 0):

If your cloud function gets invoked less than 125k/month you don't get charged anything on the Spark plan (free), for more details and up to date information on pricing and plan specific quota always reference the official firebase pricing page (https://firebase.google.com/pricing).